# Qt UI class (Clion)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, clion

I've been studying c++, but only for console application.

I'm trying to introduce myself in GUI applications with c++, since I'm working with CLion, I've noticed a Qt UI class, but I don't know how to use it.

Anyone know how to use this class, for create GUI apps (create events,...,).
I don't know if it's mandatory to install some extensions or not.

I'm a little bit lost in this area, so if anyone could help me, I would be grateful to you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe the [**Qt Creator** IDE](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source) can be of help since the design of UI can be just dragging can editing so it is very friendly to starters.
Of course, you can edit the code **Qt Creator** generates.

As a matter of fact, I started working on Gt UI by dragging the components and got amazed at the 'talent' of me creating a simple GUI app in a minute!

Below is an example UI interface of Qt Creator. Have fun with Qt!

[image: Qt Creator UI]